# access inserted, deleted clomns gernericly on a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I like to feed a change log table by an update trigger. The software what is using the table, can change the table design. So I like to compare the old against the new value, column by column, by comparing inserted and deleted. If there is a difference a log entry must be written. Unfortunately, I didn’t find a solution to get the value of the inserted, deleted table by the column name @col of the cursor. I tried several things with EXEC, inserted is not accessible in this context.

How can I access the column value of inserted, deleted by a generic code?

I would be very glad if somebody can help me out.

Cheers

LAG_Artikel_Log Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LAG_Artikel_Log](
[LaufNr] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ArtikelNrLAG] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ErstelltAm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ErstelltVon] [varchar](30) NULL,
[EigenschaftName] [varchar](256) NULL,
[EigenschaftWertAlt] [varchar](256) NULL,
[EigenschaftWertNeu] [varchar](256) NULL,
```

Trigger:

```
ALTER   TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_LAG_Artikel_Log]
   ON [dbo].[LAG_Artikel] AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Insert statements for trigger here--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @col VARCHAR(128)

    DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)
    SET @tableName = 'LAG_Artikel'

    DECLARE cursor_col CURSOR
        FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS ic
        WHERE ic.TABLE_NAME = @tableName

        OPEN cursor_col

            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_col INTO @col
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN

                    IF inserted.@col != deleted.@col
                        BEGIN
                        ----------------------------if not same ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                            INSERT INTO LAG_Artikel_Log(ArtikelNrLAG,   ErstelltAm,    ErstelltVon,   EigenschaftName, EigenschaftWertNeu, EigenschaftWertAlt)
                                SELECT                  i.ArtikelNrLAG, SYSDATETIME(), i.ErstelltVon, @col,          , i.@col            , d.@col
                            FROM inserted AS i
                            INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON i.ArtikelNrLAG = d.ArtikelNrLAG
                        END

                    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_col INTO @col
                END
        CLOSE cursor_col
    DEALLOCATE cursor_col
END
```

Comment: This is a terrible design! You need to use dynamic sql to build the correct statement by reading the columns from information_schema. This trigger will be a performance bottleneck, the cursor and multiple inserts will be run as part of the transaction performing the update, reducing its performance and concurrency.

Comment: Ay better idea how to implement a change log for a dynamically changing table?

Comment: Dynamically changing table sounds like an antipattern, is a relational database the correct tool for the job?

Comment: _dynamically changining table_ There is your real problem. Tables represent real things and should rarely change. And when they do change, the vast majority of other systems require an impact analysis and updates to the other dependent parts of your "system" to validate that everything continues to work correctly.  And this `IF inserted.@col != deleted.@col` is just invalid syntax - you would need dynamic sql to do this. I should also add that a trigger must handle mutiple rows in the inserted / deleted tables. Don't assume a single row exists.

Comment: `IF inserted.@col != deleted.@col` is to show the whished functionality. I tried to use sp with dynamically generated queries. Unfortunately the return type would variate and the inserted deleted tables are unknown in the executed sp. I can not change the logic of the program what is modifying the tables.